# Reactive form only one checked checkbox

Tags: angular, forms

I have a form like this:

```
for (const referential of this.referentials) {
      referential.values.forEach(referentialValue => {
        const newFormGroup = new FormGroup({
          value: new FormControl(referentialValue.value, [Validators.required]),
          libelle: new FormControl(referentialValue.libelle, [Validators.required]),
          primaryColor: new FormControl(referentialValue.primaryColor),
          secondaryColor: new FormControl(referentialValue.secondaryColor),
          borderColor: new FormControl(referentialValue.borderColor),
          default: new FormControl(false)
        });
        this.referentialArray.push(newFormGroup);
      });
    }
    this.form.addControl('referentials', this.referentialArray);
    this.form.disable();
    this.initialValue = this.form.value;
```

and the html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let _ of referentialArray.controls; let i = index">
          <tr [formGroupName]="i">
            <td><input type="text"
                formControlName="value"></td>
            <td><input type="text"
                formControlName="libelle"></td>
            <td>
              <input class="w-full max-w-40"
                type="color"
                formControlName="primaryColor">
              <input class="w-full max-w-40"
                type="color"
                formControlName="secondaryColor">
              <input class="w-full max-w-40"
                type="color"
                formControlName="borderColor">
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <input type="checkbox"
                formControlName="default"
                (change)="onChange(i)">
            </td>
            <td>
              <app-equipment-preview [equipment]="equipment"
                [primaryColor]="_.get('primaryColor').value"
                [secondaryColor]="_.get('secondaryColor').value"
                [borderColor]="_.get('borderColor').value"></app-equipment-preview>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="isEnabled">
              <img class="w-5 cursor-pointer"
                (click)="this.deleteLine(i)"
                src="../../../../../../assets/icons/bin.svg">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
```

I would like to add the impossibility of selecting multiple checkboxes, only one is selectable, so I tried this:

```
public onChange(i): void {
    this.form.value.referentials.forEach((val, index) => {
      if (i !== index && val.default) {
        val.default = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

this method is called when the user clicks on a checkbox, but it doesn't work, i tried different things with patchValue but nothing works, you have any ideas?

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to achieve? Do you want all other checkboxes to be false? What is val.default in your IF condition in the last part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not assign value directly to set. You have to go through the patchValue() or setValue() for it.

```
public onChange(i: number): void {
    (this.form.controls['referentials'] as FormArray).controls.forEach((item: FormGroup, index: number) => {
      if (i !== index && item.controls['default'].value) {
        item.controls['default'].setValue(false);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it work well with your workaround